# How to Print file with using Task Scheduled

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

*My console Application is working when double clicking application and it downloads .zip files from mail then send pdfs to printer. However, Problem is that when I use task scheduled to run this app, it reads mail then download .zip files but it doesnt send pdf files to printer. I didnt Understand what problem is that. How can I  handle this ?*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            ExchangeService exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail", "password);
            exchange.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

                if (exchange != null)
                {

                        SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
                        FindItemsResults<Item> result = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, new ItemView(20));

                        foreach (Item item in result)
                        {

                                EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id);

                                message.IsRead = true;
                                message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

                                List<Attachment> zipList = message.Attachments.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(".zip")).ToList();

                                foreach (Attachment Attachment in zipList)
                                {

                                        if (Attachment is FileAttachment)
                                        {
                                            FileAttachment f = Attachment as FileAttachment;

                                            f.Load("C:\\pdfFiles\\" + f.Name);



                                            string zipPath = @"C:\pdfFiles\" + f.Name;
                                            string extractPath = @"C:\pdfFiles\" + Path.GetRandomFileName();

                                            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);

                                            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(extractPath, "*.pdf",
                                                         SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                                            foreach (string path in filePaths)
                                            {

                                                    SendToPrinter(path);

                                            }


                                        }



                                }


                        }


                }

        }


      static void SendToPrinter(string path)
            {
        var printerName = "EPSON L310 Series";

             ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        info.Verb = "PrintTo";
                        info.FileName = filePath;
                        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        info.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
                        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                        Process p = new Process();
                        p.StartInfo = info;
                        p.Start();

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
     }
```

**By the way, code which is bottom work but I need to use above**

```
static void SendToPrinter(string path)
        {
      PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

       pdf.LoadFromFile(path);

       pdf.Print();
       pdf.Dispose();
   }
```

Comment: do you have acrobat reader app ?

Comment: Examine Event Viewer's 'Application Log' sub-section that should contain logged error and description in case your application throws exception during its execution. Also, in `SendToPrinter` method you are assigning a value to `info.FileName` from a variable `filePath`, you probably meant to write `path` parameter of the method.

Comment: yes I have. As I said, when double clicking it is working. It is not working when app started  by Task scheduled @Clint

Answer (score 0):

> My console Application is working when double clicking application

It appears that taskscheduler is configured to run under a different account than *currently logged in user*.
Check the user-account that is configured in the task scheduler to trigger the console app and ensure that its the same account/user that you have logged in to the computer as.

**`Edit Task > General > Security Options > When running the task use the following account > Select *your* account`**

If your task is *interactive* (has a GUI) *Checkmark* `Run only when user is logged on`

[image]